# How to add an image to an svg container using D3.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, svg, d3.js

I've created a sample Asp.Net MVC 4 application where I've used D3.js to append an SVG element and then inside the SVG I've appended a text element (see code below).  This all works fine until I try to append an img to the SVG using a local png file.  The img gets appended to the DOM, but the img is not rendered on the page.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here, and how to go about fixing it?

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 200)
        .attr("height", 100)
        .style("border", "1px solid black");

    var text = svg.selectAll("text")
        .data([0])
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text("Testing")
        .attr("x", "40")
        .attr("y", "60");

    var imgs = svg.selectAll("img").data([0]);
    imgs.enter()
        .append("img")
        .attr("xlink:href", "@Url.Content("~/Content/images/icons/refresh.png")")
        .attr("x", "60")
        .attr("y", "60")
        .attr("width", "20")
        .attr("height", "20");

</script>
```

@Richard Marr - Below is an attempt to do the same thing in straight HTML, which gives me the same result.  I'm not sure about my code to get the refresh.png file from the local drive this way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", 200)
                .attr("height", 100)
                .style("border", "1px solid black");

            var text = svg.selectAll("text")
                .data([0])
                .enter()
                .append("text")
                .text("Testing")
                .attr("x", "40")
                .attr("y", "60");

            var imgs = svg.selectAll("img").data([0]);
                imgs.enter()
                .append("svg:img")
                .attr("xlink:href", "file:///D:/d3js_projects/refresh.png")
                .attr("x", "60")
                .attr("y", "60")
                .attr("width", "20")
                .attr("height", "20");

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you rule out the ASP.NET aspect of this question by demonstrating the problem in regular HTML?

Comment: In SVG, I believe you want "image" instead of "img" as an element. Perhaps try that.

Comment: @cmonkey - that worked perfectly, if you will post this as an answer I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: If you are advancing onto multiple images into multiple SVG elements then establish a pattern, as seen here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202450/adding-an-image-within-a-circle-object-in-d3-javascript

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In SVG (contrasted with HTML), you will want to use `<image>` instead of `<img>` for elements.

Try changing your last block with:

```
var imgs = svg.selectAll("image").data([0]);
            imgs.enter()
            .append("svg:image")
            ...
```

Comment: Would be better if you show the xlink:href tag, which a user will need to use your solution. Also, data is not needed.

Comment: please add `xlink-href`,width,height parts  as well

Answer (score 116):

```
nodeEnter.append("svg:image")
.attr('x', -9)
.attr('y', -12)
.attr('width', 20)
.attr('height', 24)
.attr("xlink:href", "resources/images/check.png")
```

Answer (score 6):

My team also wanted to add images inside d3-drawn circles, and came up with the following ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/duhaime/q51ok9jc/)):

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="timeline.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
    integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="./timeline.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="timeline"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

timeline.css:

```
.axis path,
.axis line,
.tick line,
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

timeline.js:

```
// container target
var elem = ".timeline";

var props = {
  width: 1000,
  height: 600,
  class: "timeline-point",

  // margins
  marginTop: 100,
  marginRight: 40,
  marginBottom: 100,
  marginLeft: 60,

  // data inputs
  data: [
    {
      x: 10,
      y: 20,
      key: "a",
      image: "https://unsplash.it/300/300",
      id: "a"
    },
    {
      x: 20,
      y: 10,
      key: "a",
      image: "https://unsplash.it/300/300",
      id: "b"
    },
    {
      x: 60,
      y: 30,
      key: "a",
      image: "https://unsplash.it/300/300",
      id: "c"
    },
    {
      x: 40,
      y: 30,
      key: "a",
      image: "https://unsplash.it/300/300",
      id: "d"
    },
    {
      x: 50,
      y: 70,
      key: "a",
      image: "https://unsplash.it/300/300",
      id: "e"
    },
    {
      x: 30,
      y: 50,
      key: "a",
      image: "https://unsplash.it/300/300",
      id: "f"
    },
    {
      x: 50,
      y: 60,
      key: "a",
      image: "https://unsplash.it/300/300",
      id: "g"
    }
  ],

  // y label
  yLabel: "Y label",
  yLabelLength: 50,

  // axis ticks
  xTicks: 10,
  yTicks: 10

}

// component start
var Timeline = {};

/***
*
* Create the svg canvas on which the chart will be rendered
*
***/

Timeline.create = function(elem, props) {

  // build the chart foundation
  var svg = d3.select(elem).append('svg')
      .attr('width', props.width)
      .attr('height', props.height);

  var g = svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'point-container')
      .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + props.marginLeft + "," + props.marginTop + ")");

  var g = svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'line-container')
      .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + props.marginLeft + "," + props.marginTop + ")");

  var xAxis = g.append('g')
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (props.height - props.marginTop - props.marginBottom) + ")");

  var yAxis = g.append('g')
    .attr("class", "y axis");

  svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "y label")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("y", 1)
    .attr("x", 0 - ((props.height - props.yLabelLength)/2) )
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .text(props.yLabel);

  // add placeholders for the axes
  this.update(elem, props);
};

/***
*
* Update the svg scales and lines given new data
*
***/

Timeline.update = function(elem, props) {
  var self = this;
  var domain = self.getDomain(props);
  var scales = self.scales(elem, props, domain);

  self.drawPoints(elem, props, scales);
};


/***
*
* Use the range of values in the x,y attributes
* of the incoming data to identify the plot domain
*
***/

Timeline.getDomain = function(props) {
  var domain = {};
  domain.x = props.xDomain || d3.extent(props.data, function(d) { return d.x; });
  domain.y = props.yDomain || d3.extent(props.data, function(d) { return d.y; });
  return domain;
};


/***
*
* Compute the chart scales
*
***/

Timeline.scales = function(elem, props, domain) {

  if (!domain) {
    return null;
  }

  var width = props.width - props.marginRight - props.marginLeft;
  var height = props.height - props.marginTop - props.marginBottom;

  var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain(domain.x);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain(domain.y);

  return {x: x, y: y};
};


/***
*
* Create the chart axes
*
***/

Timeline.axes = function(props, scales) {

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(scales.x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(props.xTicks)
    .tickFormat(d3.format("d"));

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(scales.y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(props.yTicks);

  return {
    xAxis: xAxis,
    yAxis: yAxis
  }
};


/***
*
* Use the general update pattern to draw the points
*
***/

Timeline.drawPoints = function(elem, props, scales, prevScales, dispatcher) {
  var g = d3.select(elem).selectAll('.point-container');
  var color = d3.scale.category10();

  // add images
  var image = g.selectAll('.image')
    .data(props.data)

  image.enter()
    .append("pattern")
    .attr("id", function(d) {return d.id})
    .attr("class", "svg-image")
    .attr("x", "0")
    .attr("y", "0")
    .attr("height", "70px")
    .attr("width", "70px")
    .append("image")
      .attr("x", "0")
      .attr("y", "0")
      .attr("height", "70px")
      .attr("width", "70px")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {return d.image})

  var point = g.selectAll('.point')
    .data(props.data);

  // enter
  point.enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "point")
      .on('mouseover', function(d) {
        d3.select(elem).selectAll(".point").classed("active", false);
        d3.select(this).classed("active", true);
        if (props.onMouseover) {
          props.onMouseover(d)
        };
      })
      .on('mouseout', function(d) {
        if (props.onMouseout) {
          props.onMouseout(d)
        };
      })

  // enter and update
  point.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return scales.x(d.x); 
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { 
      return scales.y(d.y); 
    })
    .attr("r", 30)
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      if (props.pointStroke) {
        return d.color = props.pointStroke;
      } else {
        return d.color = color(d.key);
      }
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      if (d.image) {
        return ("url(#" + d.id + ")");
      }

      if (props.pointFill) {
        return d.color = props.pointFill;
      } else {
        return d.color = color(d.key);
      }
    });

  // exit
  point.exit()
    .remove();

  // update the axes
  var axes = this.axes(props, scales);
  d3.select(elem).selectAll('g.x.axis')
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .call(axes.xAxis);

  d3.select(elem).selectAll('g.y.axis')
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .call(axes.yAxis);
};


$(document).ready(function() {
  Timeline.create(elem, props);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why, but the image should not be duplicated, tripled, etc ... should remove the previous one and load it again but with another rotation data. This is my code:

data.csv
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15vb8.png)

```
d3.csv("data/data.csv").then(function(data){
//console.log(data);
// Clean data
formattedData = data.map(function(id){
id.rot_1 = +id.rot_1;
        id.trans_1 = +id.trans_1;
        return id;
});
// First run of the visualization
update(formattedData[0]);})

$("#play-button")
.on("click", function(){
    var button = $(this);
    if (button.text() == "Play"){
        button.text("Pause");
        interval = setInterval(step, 1000);            
    }
    else {
        button.text("Play");
        clearInterval(interval);
    }})

function step(){
// At the end of our data, loop back
time = (time < 76) ? time+1 : 0
update(formattedData[time]); }

function update(data) {
// Standard transition time for the visualization
var t = d3.transition()
    .duration(1000);

//console.log(d3.selectAll(data));    
//console.log(data)

// original
var imgs1 = g.append("image") // en vez de g es svg
.attr("xlink:href", "img/picturetest.png");

// EXIT old elements not present in new data.
imgs1.exit()
    .attr("class", "exit")
    .selectAll("svg:image")
    .remove();

//console.log(data)

// ENTER new elements present in new data.
imgs1.enter()
    .append("svg:image") // svg:image
    //.attr("xlink:href", "img/picturetest.png")
    .attr("class", "enter")
    .merge(imgs1)
    .transition(t)
        .attr("x", 0) // 150
        .attr("y", 0) // 80
        .attr("width", 200)
        .attr("height", 200)
        .attr("transform", "rotate("+data.rot_1+") translate("+data.trans_1+")" ); }`
```

Answer (score -4):

```
 var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .style("width", 200)
        .style("height", 100)
```