# d3 pattern displacement issue on circles

Tags: javascript, image, design-patterns, d3.js

http://jsfiddle.net/LsMZp/37/

I'm having issues stabilizing the patterns in this mock.

how do I ensure the image is always centrally aligned - it seems to jump around depending on its location/scale.

here is the code to this issue. Hoping the solution can be applied to this force chart example.

[d3.js Force Chart - image/node linkage and animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289031/d3-js-force-chart-image-node-linkage-and-animation)

```
function addUserPatterns(patternsSvg, userData){

    $.each(userData, function( index, value ) {
        var defs = patternsSvg.append('svg:defs');
                    defs.append('svg:pattern')
                        .attr('id', "--"+index+"-"+value.userName.toLowerCase())
                        .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
                        .attr('width', 100)
                        .attr('height',100)
                        .append('svg:image')
                        .attr('xlink:href', value.userImage)
                        .attr('x', 0)
                        .attr('y', 0)
                        .attr('width', 100)
                        .attr('height', 100);
    });    



                var circle = patternsSvg.append("svg:g")
                    .selectAll("circle")
                        .data(userData);

                       //enter
                       circle 
                        .enter()
                        .append("svg:circle")
                        .attr("r", 50)
                        .style("fill", function(d, i) {
                            var imgUrl = "--"+i+"-"+d.userName.toLowerCase();
                            return "url(#"+imgUrl+")"; 
                        })
                       .attr("cy", function(d){
                           return  random(0, 143);
                       })
                       .attr("cx", function(d){
                           return  random(0, 143);
                       })

    function random(min, max){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }



}

var patternsSvg = d3.select("body")
                .append('svg')
                .attr('class', 'patterns')
                .attr('width', 300)
                .attr('height', 300)
                    .append('g')
                    .attr("transform","translate(100, 100)")

var userData =[
    {
        "userName": "Ria",
    "userImage" : "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/427892889092231168/4c4Qwynr.png"
    },
     {
"userName": "Barry",        
"userImage" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdASQvEzIzE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAls/5vbx7yVLDnc/photo.jpg"
    }
]

addUserPatterns(patternsSvg, userData);
```

---

[image]

I have the images being appended to the circles ok now - but if the images are of different sizes/dimensions - is there a way to ensure the image will be fitted properly?

Is it just an assumption to ensure the images are of the same dimensions as of each other - or is there a more sophisticated way to calculate image width/height and then alter the pattern attributes as required?

http://jsfiddle.net/LsMZp/48/

```
var defs = patternsSvg.append('svg:defs');
            defs.append('svg:pattern')
                .attr('id', "--"+index+"-"+value.userName.toLowerCase())
                //.attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
                  .attr('x', 0)
                .attr('y', 0)
                .attr('width', 50)
                .attr('height', 50)
                .append('svg:image')
                .attr('xlink:href', value.userImage)
                .attr('x', 0)
                .attr('y', 0)
                .attr('width', 100)
                .attr('height', 100);
```

});

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202450/adding-an-image-within-a-circle-object-in-d3-javascript) should help. Check the comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: I don't get it though - I don't see the difference. The width/height of the pattern is the diameter of the circle?

Comment: <defs><pattern id="--1-barry" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"><image xlink:href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdASQvEzIzE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAls/5vbx7yVLDnc/photo.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"></image></pattern></defs>    http://jsfiddle.net/LsMZp/38/

Comment: <defs id="mdef">
        <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0" height="40" width="40">
          <image x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" xlink:href="http://www.e-pint.com/epint.jpg"></image>
        </pattern>
  </defs>

Comment: I've removed the "patternUnits" property - but now the image is blurry - http://jsfiddle.net/LsMZp/39/

Comment: It becomes clearer - when I set the height/width of the pattern to the radius - http://jsfiddle.net/LsMZp/40/

Comment: _ Its looking better - but - Brody's image is not aligned as well as it could be - some grey areas around the top - the quality of the images is also questionable - http://jsfiddle.net/LsMZp/46/ any suggestions?

Comment: same with Theron- http://jsfiddle.net/LsMZp/47/