# Change color to image in js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I use this nice [graph](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045).

In

```
{"name":"Napoleon","group":1},
```

`group` needs to fill a color:

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
```

But if I want to save in `group` url (to image. So, I can see images in circles), how will be it looks like in **html**?

Thanks!

Comment: This [question and answer]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202450/adding-an-image-within-a-circle-object-in-d3-javascript/19204833#19204833) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SVG you use a pattern to fill with an image then link to it. To keep your document 'data driven' and in the spirit of D3 you can set the pattern up like this in d3 (where `urls` is an array of image urls you are going to use).

```
d3.select('svg')
    .append('defs')
        .selectAll('pattern')
        .data(urls)
        .enter()
            .append('pattern')
                .attr({
                    'id': function(d, i){return 'my_pattern_' + i;},
                    'patternUnits':'userSpaceOnUse',
                    'width': dotSize,
                    'height': dotSize
                }).append('image')
                    .attr({
                        'xlink:href': function(d){return d;},
                        'x': 0,
                        'y': 0,
                        'width': dotSize,
                        'height': dotSize
                     })
```

Then when you want to use the image as a fill simply add the attribute to the relent object as

```
    .attr('fill', function(d, i){return 'url(#my_pattern_'+i+')'})
```

Of course, you will probably want to be able to map the exiting group to the relevant pattern id in the same way you can use `color()` to get the categories colour.

---

Here is a working example at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lk7TA/) which renders the facebook logo (a raster file) inside an SVG circle.

**Result:**

[image: Result of SVG pattern applied to circle]

**Source image:**

[image: The source file]

Comment: Is the plan for each group to have its own icon?

Comment: it does not matter :)

Comment: Yes, because if it was group based (which I have assumed) I would do it like http://jsfiddle.net/jmAE3/

Comment: can you answer on this question& https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23061717/photos-in-circles-on-graph