# Photos in circles on graph

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have **misarables.json**:

```
{
    "nodes":[
    {"name":"Myriel","group":1,"photo":"https://www.facebookbrand.com/img/assets/asset.f.logo.lg.png"},
        {"name":"Napoleon","group":1,"photo":"https://www.facebookbrand.com/img/assets/asset.f.logo.lg.png"},
    {"name":"Mlle.Baptistine","group":1, "photo":"https://www.facebookbrand.com/img/assets/asset.f.logo.lg.png"}
    ],
     "links":[
    {"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":2,"target":0,"value":8}
    ]
}
```

So, every node has name, group and photo. I use [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4600693) graph to visualisate that json (json and html in different files). How I need to change **js**, to show photos in circles in that graph?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Force-Directed Layout of d3-js support image as node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306250/does-force-directed-layout-of-d3-js-support-image-as-node)

Comment: no. In every node I will have unique photo

Comment: @tim The principle is the same, you would just assign the image link based on the data, something like `.attr("xlink:href",function(d) {return d.photo;})`.