# How to set SVG circle fill with SVG from CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, geometry

So I tried variations of:

```
circle {
    stroke: black;
    //fill: brown;
    fill-opacity: .5;
    fill:url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
}
```

yet I can not get a correct (or any fill) of SVG circle with predefined svg image. Is it possible from CSS or how  to do it from js?

Comment: It seems like the common way to fill SVG with images is through Patterns, have you looked at that? Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image

Comment: This [SO question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202450/adding-an-image-within-a-circle-object-in-d3-javascript) deals specifically with patterns within a circle.

Answer (score 2):

The fill value has to be a colour or a paint server (gradient or pattern).  You can't just give it an image like that I'm afraid.

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#FillProperty