# Adding image to svg container using d3 not working on FF and Safari

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm using the solution proposed here [How to add an image to an svg container using D3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567809/how-to-add-an-image-to-an-svg-container-using-d3-js/34165717#34165717), like this

```
svg.selectAll()
        .data(chart.data.values)
        .enter()
        .append('svg:image')
        .attr('class', 'logo-legend')
        .attr('x', function (d, i) {
                return d.position;
            }
        )
        .attr('y', 251)
        .attr('xlink:href', function (d, i) {
            return d.fileName;
        });
```

Which works on Chrome, but it's not working on FF and Safari. I can see on firebug that the images are being created on the html, but they are just not showing. Any idea why?

I can see that on Chrome the element created is

```
<image class="logo-legend" x="46.5" y="251" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/img/services/logo.png"></image>
```

While on FF is

```
<image class="logo-legend" x="46.5" y="251" href="/img/services/logo.png">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The W3 spec requires explicit height/width attributes.  From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag) (bolding mine):

> There are some important things to take note of (referenced from the
>   W3 specs):
>
> - If you do not set the x or y attributes, they will be set to 0.
> - If you do not set the height or width attributes, **they will be set to
>     0.**
> - Having a height or width attribute of 0 will disable rendering of the
>     image.

Comment: I added those attributes on my class,
.logo-legend {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}

Comment: @MaryliaGutierrez, try setting them as *attributes* instead of as a style.